# Quantum Mechanics with non-Abelian gauge fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, yang-mills

In "conventional" quantum mechanics, in the presence of electromagnetic fields, we use minimal substitution in the Hamiltonian in the simplest case. I.e.
$$H=\frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m}\rightarrow \frac{(\vec{p}+e\vec{A}/c)^2}{2m}$$
What if one wants to consider more complicated gauge fields $$\vec{A}=\vec{A}^\alpha t_\alpha$$ where $t_\alpha$ are the generators of the corresponding gauge group? Can we simply minimally substitute that as well?

If so, I guess the gauge transformation for the quantum states changes as well. If so, how?

I've tried searching for this in multiple resources but found nothing. I even tried Quantum Field theory books that treat quantum mechanics as a $(0+1)-$dimensional QFT, but found nothing.

Comment: Show your work with minimal subtraction: you are barking up the right tree. You are totally comfortable with the nonabelian generalization in QFT, right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Only the basics. I tried replacing the derivative found in $p$ with the covariant derivative (as one usually does in QFT), so I think the answer to my own question is yes. Yet, due to the nature of the complexity of non-Abelian fields, I though I might ask here to see if there's any complication I haven't thought about.

Comment: @CosmasZachos In Yang-Mills theory, when we introduce a non-Abelian field, we have $N$ (for $SU(N)$) associated scalar fields which transform under a specific representation of $SU(N)$ (I think they transform as vectors). But I don't know how the wavefunction would transform in QM when we introduce, say, an $SU(N)$ gauge field. I guess maybe the question should have been "how do quantum states transform in an $SU(N)$ gauge theory?" I would be able to generalize it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how the wavefunction would transform in QM when we introduce, say, an ()gauge field. I guess maybe the question should have been "how do quantum states transform in an ()
> gauge theory?"

Look at your hamiltonian in electromagnetism,
$$H=\frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m}\rightarrow \frac{(\vec{p}+e\vec{A}/c)^2}{2m},$$
noting that, e.g., in the coordinate representation, ($\vec p= -i\hbar \nabla$), the wavefunction $\psi(x) \to e^{-ie\theta(x) /c\hbar} \psi(x)$, and the
vector potential $\vec A \to \vec A + \nabla \theta$, so that
$H\psi$ transforms just like $\psi$, regardless of the action of the derivative,
$$
H\psi \to e^{-ie\theta(x) /c\hbar} H \psi(x).
$$
Confirm this! That is, the derivatives have been supplemented in such a way that "covariant" operators like your *H* acting on the wavefunction transform  like the wavefunction itself, even though the "angle" *θ* depends on *x*.

This is the key trick you may replicate for, e.g., *SU(N)* spinor wavefunctions. The simplest case is *N*-dimensional spinors (complex vectors), each of whose components you might think of as a wavefunction itself,  now acted upon by *N×N* matrices, of which there are $N^2 -1$, indexed by *α*. So, suppress these *N* spinor indices and the matrix indices for simplicity, and only carry the labels of the matrices *t*.

You then saturate those with $N^2-1$ vector potentials,
$$\vec{A}=\vec{A}^\alpha t_\alpha,$$
and plug into the hamiltonian of EM, which is now an *N×N* matrix, with the *N×N* identity matrix  multiplying all other operators like the momentum.

Now, the transformation of these spinors is not just multiplication by a complex exponential as before, but, instead, by an *SU(N)* unitary matrix,
$$
U(x)=e^{-ie{\theta^\alpha(x)}~ t_\alpha/c\hbar},
$$
with $N^2 -1$ angles, instead of the one such for EM.

To ensure the covariant operator property, above, because these matrices do not commute with each other but obey an elaborate Lie algebraic structure, the vector potentials must now transform more elaborately,
$$
\vec A \to U\vec A U^{-1} -i\frac{c\hbar}{e} U\nabla U^{-1}.
$$
You now have to use more elaborate identities to prove covariance, and most decent QFT texts do that (no field theory involved, just nonabelian medium-hard manipulations), and you are done. (In the nonabelian case, given the fancier transformation laws of the vector potentials, the pure vector potential hamiltonian is not the Maxwell hamiltonian anymore, it has a few more wrinkles, but the spirit is the same.)

Comment: Very informative answer! Thank you

Comment: Are $\theta^a$ real or can they also be complex? Morever, in the last equation, isn't $U^{-1}=U^\dagger$ in the case of real $\theta^a$? Also, I guess $\psi$ transforms under the fundamental representation. But what about $A$? Is it the adjoint?

Comment: The θs are real. Yes, the inverse of a unitary matrix is the adjoint. Ψ is in the fundamental, but if it were in another rep, the ts would be too. A is *always* in the adjoint, no matter what!